# Can not find the good syntax for a vim sustitute pattern

Tags: vim

I have a bunch of `t_` prefixed fonction names in a header file and i would like to remove this prefix from some of them.

I have ended by typing :

`:s/\(\s+\)t_\([^(]+\)(/\1\2(/c`

But vim complains with `Pattern not found`
What is wrong in my pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put a backslash before `+` to give it its quantifier meaning. You can also probably simplify it using `\<` to match the start of a word instead of capturing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking the problem down, first the search:

```
/\v\s+\zst_\ze.*\(
```

Now the substitution:

```
:s///\c
```

We can reuse a search pattern simply typing an empty search on the substitution

OBS: I suppose your functions have `()` at the end of the line, so `.*()`.
Another thing; `\zs` and `\ze` to match only `t_`, for more see: `:h \zs`.

If you are using neovim you can see what happens befor hitting enter, just put these lines on your init.vim:

```
if has("nvim")
    set inccommand=nosplit
endif
```